# How to use text template?

Tags: c#

I have a header and footer text file, both files are long and constant for all use cases. I dont want to declare it in the code or read them in runtime.

```
const string header = "some very long text in header";
const string footer = "some very long text in footer";
string content = "my CONTENT"; 

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(header);
sb.Append(content);
sb.Append(footer);

var allText = sb.toString(); // all text here
```

Is it possible if I could use some text template? and then generate all the information like those Mustache template engine in HTML?

Example: `template.txt`

```
some very long text in header

<%= content %>

some very long text in footer
```

Output

```
some very long text in header

my CONTENT

some very long text in footer
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using *Linq*:

```
var header = File
  .ReadLines(@"C:\MyHeader.txt");

var footer = File
  .ReadLines(@"C:\MyFooter.txt");

var lines = header
  .Concat(new String[] {"My Content"})
  .Concat(footer);

...

var allText = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
  lines);
```

**Edit**: if you have both *header* and *footer* in *one file* (not a good practice) you can use `Select()`. For instance if `<%= content %>` marks the line that should be changed for the content:

```
  var lines = File
    .ReadLines(@"C:\HeaderAndFooter.txt")
    .Select(line => line == "<%= content %>" ? "MyContent" : line);
  ...
  var allText = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
      lines);
```

Comment: that a neat solution, if i just want my header and footer in one file, how can i do that? use view engine as suggested by @CSharper?

Comment: @ Tim: At that case you can slightly modify the Linq, e.g. use `Select()`, see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use for that purpose the `Razor view Engine` [ASP.NET Razor](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-(c))

This enginge is not limited to process HTML files. It can be used for all text files.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create templates you could use `Antlr4.StringTemplate` which essential does what you wish, by default its uses'<' and '>' or '$' as delimiter